# What pins should I use when blinking AtTiny13 with arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-ide, attiny

I'm trying to program AtTiny13 using Arduino IDE. I have connected the atTiny to my PC using USBasp programer.

I want to write a simple blink application to test whether it works or not. Which pins should I blink?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an Arduino library that supports that chip, to make it appear in the Tools > Board list.  The library docs will tell you which pins then correspond to which Arduino digital I/Os. From that you can decide which pin to attach an LED to (with resistor) and how to edit the blink sketch.

Example: http://www.instructables.com/id/Pimp-Your-Chocolates-with-Arduino-IDE-and-ATtiny13/step2/Program-the-ATtiny13/

Comment: There's already Attiny13 in the menu. Should I then just use pins 1-8?

Comment: You could of course just try using software "pin 1" and seeing if that works... it's likely that this is ATTiny Port B bit 0 (PB0) which appears on physical pin 5 of the 8-pin DIP chip (see http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2535.pdf for other packages).

Comment: For more insight, look at file pins_arduino.h for the ATTiny13 somewhere within your ...\arduino\hardware\arduino\??? directory.  I am assuming that at some point you added the core definition files that included ATTiny13, as I don't have them on my machine. Note that different core definitions could assign the Arduino pins to different physical pins.

Comment: Shoot, I meant that Arduino digital ZERO (D0) should appear on pin 5 (PB0) of the DIP8, etc.

Comment: I have just downloaded Arduino IDE. Maybe ATTiny13 was included - or it just appears to be included but doesn't work as [my current experience with it](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3150/how-to-add-the-f-switch-for-avrdude-in-arduino-ide) would suggest.

Comment: Programming the ATTiny is of course a separate problem. And I'm guessing you can't tell if your problem with blink is in the programming or the program pin assignments. Hmmm.

Comment: When you use AVRDUDE to check the device signature, do you at least get a consistent signature value? If not there's something wrong with the electrical connection.

Comment: I can't tell, but as soon as I get over uploading problem, I'll face the unknown pin number problem. So I'm solving them simultaneously.

Comment: And don't get any value, it just says that `Expected signature for ATtiny13 is 1E 90 07` but doesn't output the wrong value. Avter strungling with avrdude for a second time, I find it a very unhelpful software for anyone, who is not 100% sure that he's doing everything right.

Comment: avrdude -p t13 -t
   ... should return device signature. See http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/using_avrprog.html and this tutorial looks helpful tho not for t13: http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/avrdude.html

Comment: And presumably you have docs: http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude.html, specifically command line flags: http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_4.html#Option-Descriptions

Comment: I would try to install the attiny13 board as per the instructables page. There shouldn't have been a attiny13 in the default install of arduino. As you don't know where it came from, and what core it is using, you're better of starting from scratch. That way you also know how the pin numbers are mapped. avrdude is a pain in the ***, but in my experience it was always right when complaining about signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Because pins 0 and 1 (physical 5,6) are PWM's you should keep them for later ...
and you still have A3 and A2 for analogWrite so,
you should use Pin 2 (Physical 7, next to +5V) like this :

add this in the setup function

```
pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
```

And add this in your loop function:

```
digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
```

[image: In case you forget]

For reference : 
[SparkFun's Help guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/tiny-avr-programmer-hookup-guide/attiny85-use-hints)

Remember : Physical pin "1", reset, has a dot  marked on it.